# How do I create forms involving several entities in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

New on SO, I hope my question is relevant and fits to the rules.

I am trying the python micro-framework Flask ; so far, so good. Given 2 entities as below (one Truc to Many TrucAttribute):

Truc :

```
from app import db
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, ForeignKey
import TrucAttribute

class Truc(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'app_truc'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, prymary_key = True)
    owned_attributs_de_truc = db.relationship('TrucAttribute', backref="truc", cascade="all, delete-orphan", lazy="dynamic")

# Truc business methods ...
```

TrucAttribute :

```
from app import db
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, ForeignKey
import Truc

class TrucAttribute(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    truc_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('app_truc.id'))
    truc_owner = relationship("Truc", backref="attributs_de_truc")

    @staticmethod #return a list usable for forms
    def form_list():
        attributs = TrucAttributes.query.all()
        attributs_list = []
        for attribut in attributs:
        attributs_list.append((unicode(attribut.id), unicode(attribut.name))
        return attributs_list
```

forms.py :

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import SelectField
from app.models.trucAttributes import TrucAttribute

class CreateTrucForm(Form):
    truc_attribute = SelectField(u'Truc Attribute', choices=TrucAttribute.form_list())
```

code from create.html:

```
Truc Attribute :
{{  form.truc_attribute() }}
```

and the controller:

```
@app.route('/create/truc', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def createTruc():
    form = CreateTrucForm()
    return render_template('create/CreateTruc.html', form=form)
```

How do I create a Truc creation form with a select-list of TrucAttribute ? Until now, I only created very simple forms, based on the [Flask Mega Tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world).

Thanks !

Comment: Could you also post the code that creates your form?  This can be done with SelectField, but the list needs to be populated before rendering the template.  If you can share whatever you have now, where select list does not work, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: I added the solution I imagined above. Is it the right way to do it ?

Comment: It sort of looks fine. What happens when you run it?    I would leave out unicoding attribut.id as it is an integer and can be treated as such,  making it attributs_list.append((attribut.id, unicode(attribut.name)).    Does your truc_attribute have entries? Does anything get displayed on your field? If you add  "print attributs_list" just before the return statement in your static method, what happens? Does it run the code? Does the output look ok?

Comment: It does get displayed in the field, and the code is running fine. Was just wondering if the way I proceed with my static method is ok or if I should do it otherwise.

Comment: Let me post a reply as an answer as it allows me to format it.

Comment: Excuse me but I have no idea how to let you post a reply as an answer :$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your static method should be absolutely fine. The only thing I am not sure is how dynamic this solution is. If you end up adding or deleting from TrucAttribute, does it update? It might not if it gets queried only at startup.   I do it a bit differently and use in my app.route function just before calling render_template. Then you don't need to define choices=... in your form class.

```
form.truc_attribute.choices = [(a.id,a.name) for a in Session.query(TrucAttribute).\
                               order_by(TrucAttribute.a_name).all()]
render_template(.....)
```

But your static method should work fine. I like to order my choices alphabetically and use order_by to do exactly that.

Another tip. If you want to have the form return the corresponding id integer instead of the string the user chooses, thus simplifying your queries, you can set in your form class:

```
class CreateTrucForm(Form):
    truc_attribute = SelectField("Attribute", coerce=int)
```

and then populate the list as I just described above, you should get intergers back when you parse the form after a post request.

Hope this helps.

Hannu

Comment: Don't I query it each time I refresh the webpage ? Thanks for the tips !